# How do you get in a war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How do you get in a war in Clash of Clans?

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ)

> **Where can I find clan wars?**
>
> If you are in a clan, you can access clan wars at any time via the
>   clan wars button on left bottom corner on your screen (the button with
>   two swords crossed). From here, new clan wars can be started by clan
>   leaders and co-leaders, and you can participate in or spectate any
>   clan wars that are in progress. If a clan war is in progress, pressing
>   this button will take you directly to the map of the war zone.
>
> **How does one start a clan war?**
>
> Leaders and co-leaders can take their clan to war by opening the clan
>   war screen and pressing the “Start War” button. This will start the
>   search for an opponent clan, and you will be able to see the size of
>   the clan war you are being matched for (e.g. 15 vs 15). The clan war
>   will start immediately after an opponent clan has been found.
>
> Finding an opponent clan can take up to a few hours, but there is no
>   need to wait in the clan wars screen. You can close the screen with
>   the red “X” button and you will be notified when an opposing clan has
>   been found.
>
> **How do I participate in clan wars?**
>
> To participate in a clan war, you must be a part of a clan when a
>   leader or co-leader presses the “Start War” button. If you join the
>   clan after this point, you will become a spectator and will not be
>   able to actively participate in the clan war.